# webservice returns json data but having xml header how can we remove

Tags: asp.net, .net

Am using simple webservice ".asmx".In my web service returning some data like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

{"Table":[{"minlatency":16.0,"Time":"\/Date(1328248782660+0530)\/"},{"minlatency":7.0,"Time":"\/Date(1328248784677+0530)\/"},{"minlatency":13.0,"Time":"\/Date(1328248786690+0530)\/"},{"minlatency":6.0,"Time":"\/Date(1328248788690+0530)\/"},{"minlatency":20.0,"Time":"\/Date(1328248790707+0530)\/"}]}</string>
```

I am using:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json,  XmlSerializeString = false)]
```

after `[webmethod]`in my service,and it is giving error in `ajax callback`,i want return values  in json format.

Comment: Can you include the code for the actual method?

Comment: Technically that *is* XML, it just happens to include JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago, I found that using the following as my service

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetPointers() {
    DataTable dtmkrs = new DataTable();
    dtmkrs.Load(SPs.GetPointers().GetReader());

    string[][] pointerArray = new string[dtmkrs.Rows.Count][];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow mkrs in dtmkrs.Rows)
    {
        pointerArray[i] = new string[] { mkrs["LocationID"].ToString(), mkrs["Title"].ToString(), mkrs["Blurb"].ToString(), mkrs["Url"].ToString(), mkrs["LongLatPoint"].ToString() };
        i++;
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(pointerArray);
    dtmkrs.Dispose();
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(strJSON);
}
```

and the following javascript (using mootools)

```
new Request.JSON({
url:<url to webservice>,
method: 'GET',
onSuccess: function(resJson, respText) {
        jsonResponse = resJson;
    dropJSON();
}
}).send();
```

the previous is a function for getting Googlemaps markers from an SQL server database in ASP.NET c#

Comment: possibly not the most elegant way of doing it, but its a functional way of doing it.

Comment: giving error "Server cannot clear headers after HTTP headers have been sent".

Answer (score 0):

I have a service returning JSON which I call from jQuery and it only returns pure JSON. This is how I have the interface defined:

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Function GetNotes() As List(Of MyClassObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it using what [Ira Rainy] has suggested, or use attributes to do the same job.

using attributes, simply put the following line above your desired method(s):

```
[WebInvokeAttribute(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string DoSomething()
{
   // your code here
}
```

Hope this will fix your problem.