# removing xml tags from json data

Tags: asp.net, xml, json, web-services

I have question about json data. I can convert data from database to json data in asp.net web service but they come with xml tags. I need to remove string tags and xml information from this data. The appearance of the data is :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?

string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"

[{"ID":10,"Duration":24235},{"ID":21,"Duration":9034},{"ID":12,"Duration":13681},{"ID":1,"Duration":23053},{"ID":13,"Duration":22863},{"ID":22,"Duration":57163}]
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288270/webservice-returns-json-data-but-having-xml-header-how-can-we-remove) question, might help you

Answer (score 1):

Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports System.Collections.Generic

Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class Product

```
    Public ProductID As Integer
    Public ProductName As String
    Public VendorID As Integer
    Public GroupID As Integer
```

End Class

Public Function GetProductJSon() As String

```
    Dim ls As New List(Of Product)
    Dim Temp As String = ""
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim json As String
    Try
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString)
            Using cm As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cm.CommandText = "GetProdct"
                cm.Connection.Open()
                Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cm)
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "Product")
                Dim clsProduct As New Product
                dt = ds.Tables(0)
                For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    clsProduct.ProductID = dt.Rows(i)("ProductID")
                    clsProduct.ProductName = dt.Rows(i)("ProductName")
                    clsProduct.VendorID = dt.Rows(i)("VendorID")
                    clsProduct.GropID = dt.Rows(i)("GropID")

                    ls.Add(clsProduct)
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
        json = js.Serialize(ls)
        Return json
    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try
```

End Function

```
<WebMethod()> _

<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)> _
```

Public Sub GetProduct()

```
    Dim str As String = GetProductJSon()
    Context.Response.Clear()
    Context.Response.ContentType = "text/json"
    Context.Response.Charset = "utf-8"
    Context.Response.Write(str)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at how you're requesting the data and force ASP.NET to return JSON (which can be fiddly).

Decorate your web service method with:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetData() {
```

Then make sure to set the content type and request the data via POST:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/YourService.asmx/GetData",
    data: markers,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        // your actual data will be in data.d
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        // show error
    }
});
```

Comment: My codes are below, I used string for script method.I cannot understand what is the problem.

Comment: You're getting XML back because you're returning string. You need to request JSON and let .NET handle serialization of your object(s).